# Hamiltonian System in economics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, economics, applications

I was wondering if you know about any simple example of a Hamiltonian System that arises in economics or finances. I have been looking on the web, but I could only find one (with variables I didn't really understand). Maybe there is a simpler one (like the hamiltonian for the pendulum). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a collected volume titled *The Hamiltonian Approach to Dynamic Economics*, edited by David Cass and Karl Shell, published in 1976 by Academic Press.

It collects eight essays originally appeared on the *Journal of Economic Theory*, vol. 12, n. 1, 1976.